# Webapi Response 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I made an asp.net core web api and implemented some logic to register user.
But the issue is that whenever I call the controller from postman, it gives me 500 Internal Server Error.I also implemented an simple IActionResult to return welcome message, that also don't work. Here is my code.

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]

public class AuthController : Controller
{
    private readonly IAuthRepository _repo;
    public AuthController(IAuthRepository repo)
    {
        _repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpPost("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody]CreateUserDTO createUserDto)
    {
        createUserDto.Username=createUserDto.Username.ToLower();
        if(await _repo.UserExists(createUserDto.Username))
            return BadRequest("User With This User Name Already Exists");
        var userToCreate=new User
        {
            UserName=createUserDto.Username
        };

        var createdUser=await _repo.Register(userToCreate,createUserDto.Password);

        return Ok("user registered");
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var message="welcome message";
        return Ok(message);
    }


}
```

Looking to hear from you soon.
Thanks

Comment: That means your code is crashing. Put a breakpoint and see what is happening.

Comment: Hy Shyju, I'm using vscode and I tried this breakpoint too. But when I initiate the call from postman, control doesn't come to this. I have a very simple value controller and that works fine.

Comment: It would be good practice to implement logging and use try/catch in your actions.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in the constructor? If you're IOC isn't passing in the repo right it would give you a hard error before the code even gets to the Get action

Comment: Hey Mark Fitzpatrick,
Thanks for your help. Yes the problem was with my constructor of my AuthRepository. I forget to give the public modifier to the constructor. But now everything is fine and working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem.
The problem was with my AuthRepository constructor where I wasn't specifying the public modifier.
Here is my AuthRepository code (working)

```
public class AuthRepository : IAuthRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationDatabase _db;

    public  AuthRepository(ApplicationDatabase db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
    public async  Task<User> Login(string username, string password)
    {
        var user=await _db.Users.Where(x=>x.UserName==username).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (user==null)
            return null;
        if(!verifyPasswordHash(password,user.PasswordHash,user.PasswordSalt))
            return null;

        return user;
    }

    private bool verifyPasswordHash(string password, byte[] passwordHash, byte[] passwordSalt)
    {
        using(var hmac=new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512(passwordSalt))
        {
            var computedPasswordHash=hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            for (int i = 0; i < computedPasswordHash.Length; i++)
            {
                if (computedPasswordHash[i]!=passwordHash[i])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public async Task<User> Register(User user, string password)
    {
        byte[] passwordHash,passwordSalt;
        CreatePasswordHashSalt(password,out passwordHash,out passwordSalt);
        user.PasswordHash=passwordHash;
        user.PasswordSalt=passwordSalt;
        await _db.Users.AddAsync(user);
        _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return user;
    }

    private void CreatePasswordHashSalt(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
    {
        using(var hmac=new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA512())
        {
            passwordSalt=hmac.Key;
            passwordHash=hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
        }
    }

    public async Task<bool> UserExists(string username)
    {
        if(await _db.Users.AnyAsync(x=>x.UserName==username))
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```